# How do I make an option list that is wider when expanded than when closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to create a select list that has a fixed width, but when you click to expand it, the other options can be wider to accomodate longer strings. Kind of like a mega menu

This asp.net control is an example of what I am talking about: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/137454/Extended-DropDownList

I am looking for a html/javascript/css solution (jquery is fine). I have tried googling but I don't know what this behaviour is called.

Comment: What browser are you using? This is standard issue in most browsers. What I mean by that -- is -- the dropdown list, when clicked, will show options, and the width of that dropdown will be equal to the longest string.

Comment: [This is normal behaviour](http://jsfiddle.net/CmWwz/).

Answer (score 2):

I may have overlooked something, but like Ohgodwhy and Sheikh Heera stated, this is a pretty standard feature.  Simply using css to style the width of the select tag will set the static display width, and when the select is clicked on the results will be displayed regardless of width relative to the select container.

Here's an example:

```
<select style="width: 100px;">
<option>Short</option>
<option>This is a really really really long option</option>
</select>
```